# Regex - Why doesn't this .* (dot-star) match line-breaks?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

`/(<pre>|<code>|\[code])(.*)(</pre>|</code>|\[/code])/gi`

This works if I have something such as:

`<code>foobar</code>`

But if I were to have a line-break like this:

```
<code>
    Awesome
</code>
```

It will not match it, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You do need the [`DOTALL` modifer `/s`](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php), because the `.` dot per default excludes linebreaks.
The `/g` modifier OTOH is not legal in PHP and PCRE.

You should also use `.*?` to not match too wide.

Answer (score 6):

In PCRE, "." does not match every character, it matches every thing that isn't a newline:

> Outside a character class, a dot in the pattern matches any one character in the subject,
>   including a non-printing character, but not (by default) newline.

(http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.dot.php)

Try something like [\s\S] instead.

Comment: Or, you know, you can listen to any of the three other valid answers that popped up while I was writing mine.

Answer (score 3):

Because `.` matches every character *except newline* by default, unless you feed in the `s` switch.

See explanation of regex switches [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php).

In particular

> s (PCRE_DOTALL) If this modifier is set, **a dot metacharacter in the
>   pattern matches all characters, including newlines**. Without it,
>   newlines are excluded.

So `/(<pre>|<code>|\[code])(.*)(</pre>|</code>|\[/code])/is`.

(No `g`, use `preg_match_all`).