# PHP preg_replace not matching multiple lines

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Help! I'm doing a replace that will convert a bracketed block to a block surrounded by `<div>`s.  Please see below.

The code:

```
$data = '
<p>
{ 
asdf
asdf
asdf
}
</p>
';

echo preg_replace('%{(.*)}%m', '<div>\1</div>', $data);
```

The output should be:

```
<p>
<div>
asdf
asdf
asdf
</div>
</p>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You need the `%s` modifier as well. Else `.` won't match linebreaks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regex - Why doesn't this .\* (dot-star) match line-breaks?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8919517/regex-why-doesnt-this-dot-star-match-line-breaks)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `s` modifier instead of the `m` modifier.

The `s` modifier allows `.` to match newlines.

The `m` modifier makes `^` and `$` match the start and end of individual lines, as opposed to the start and end of the entire string.

Side-note: The preferred syntax for the replacement is `<div>$1</div>`

Comment: (I'm accepting this answer because you tied with the other one, yet you had more information)

Answer (score 2):

Use the `s` modifier.

```
preg_replace('%{(.*)}%s', '<div>\1</div>', $data);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `s` instead of `m`;

```
echo preg_replace('~\{(.*)\}~s', '<div>\1</div>', $data);
```

And just an advise, escape all chars that special for regex.